# Question about grid - 12 columns gutter widths

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm a bit confused on the best way to set up a magazine grid, 8.5"x11" page spreads. I found a great template with 12 columns from http://www.thegridsystem.org/ and the gutters are all 1p0. However, this article from Typophile, http://typophile.com/node/47265 suggests using 5mm gutters between columns of text, which is about 1.1811 picas.

Not sure what to do - having a 12-column grid is very flexible in that you can easily use it to align 2, 3 or 4 columns of text on a page, but the 1p0 gutter seems a bit narrow for columns of text. What's the best practice for using 12-column grids and setting up gutter values? Thanks.

Comment: Best practice is to not have a too narrow gutter. I think you answered your own question right there.